# Use "where" in group expressions in sql

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I need make such request: choose list of cities which include letter `i` and have appropriate number of employees. Also I need take to attention that some city could have 0 employee and that for some employee field DEBT could be null.

Table `depart`

```
debt    city
-------------
43      odesa
23      kiev
79      lviv
78      lviv
12      rivne
```

Table `empl`

```
ide     fn      ln      debt
----------------------------
3421    jed     trt     43
354     jed     res     43
43      ged     hjkhg   79
73      ghghg   gfgf    79
456     jkl     gdfg    
532     kkhg    vjv     23
45      ki      vt      
243     ki      vt      78
```

I wrote this query:

```
select depart.CITY, count (*) as numb 
from depart 
   inner join empl on  empl.DEBT=depart.DEBT
where depart.CITY like '%i%'
group by depart.CITY;
```

But I do not know how take care about that some city could have 0 employee (for example this request does not show city `rivne` which have 0 employee) and that for some employee field DEBT could be null.

I use oracle with toad.

Expected results

```
city    numb
kiev    1
rivne   0
lviv    3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To take care of criterion move `where` before group by. To allow for non-existing employees or null DEBT, use [left outer join](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries006.htm).

```
select depart.CITY, count (empl.DEBT) as numb 
  from depart 
  left join empl 
    on empl.DEBT = depart.DEBT
 where depart.CITY like '%i%'
 group by depart.CITY;
```

To get all employees grouped by department you would reverse the outer join:

```
select depart.CITY, count (empl.ide) as numb 
  from empl  
  left join depart
    on empl.DEBT = depart.DEBT
 -- Note: condition is now part of a join. This is required
 --       as part of outer join because otherwise left hand
 --       table row would be filtered out.
   and depart.CITY like '%i%'
 group by depart.CITY;
```

(Presumably `ide` is primary key of employee).
But this would not return departments without employees, and CITY would be null where department's city would not match `%i%` or empl.DEBT would be null from the start.

To solve the problem, one might extend first query with union all designed to retrieve employees without departments. But there is a question: do we want only departmentless employees, or we consider or employees not working in a city whose name contains `i` departmentless also. I've opted for second possibility.

```
select depart.CITY, count (empl.DEBT) as numb 
  from depart 
  left join empl 
    on empl.DEBT = depart.DEBT
 where depart.CITY like '%i%'
 group by depart.CITY;
select '(unknown or unmatched city)', count (*) as numb
  from empl
  left join depart
    on empl.DEBT = depart.DEBT
   and depart.CITY like '%i%'
 where depart.DEBT is null;
```

If you need distinction between employees without departments and those who work in a city not containing `i`, you might use [case](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm):

```
select case when depart.CITY like '%i%'
            then depart.CITY
            when depart.DEBT is null
            then '(No department)'
            else '(City does not match %i%)'
        end as CITY,
       count (*) as numb
  from empl
  left join depart
    on empl.DEBT = depart.DEBT
 group by 
       case when depart.CITY like '%i%'
            then depart.CITY
            when depart.DEBT is null
            then '(No department)'
            else '(City does not match %i%)'
        end
```

This query will count employees from matching cities, unmatching cities and those who have no department.

Comment: after such request I get rivne into list of cities, but numb is 1, should be 0.

Comment: @khris Please check my answer again. I've changed count(*) part.

Comment: how modify request if i want display also quantity of employee which have no department ( like 45 in empl)?

Comment: @khris Please refresh the page. There is another version of my answer.

Comment: second select gives me record where are 8 emlpoyyes, must be only 1, maybe I should write smtg like "where empl.Debt=null"

Comment: Also I'm interested if it is possible to done all this in one request like, in field city show line unknown and where store quantity of people which have no department?

Comment: this script do not show rivne where quantity of employee is 0, and displays city which does not match %i%, it shouldn't by the condition

Comment: @khris Then I didn't understand your previous comment. Could you please extend your question with sample data and expected output?

Comment: sorry, I already understand, i need change join (select from department) and change count (empl.DEBT instead of *)

Comment: the only thing is, is it possible do not display such line  "else '(City does not match %i%)'", if I take off it from script, line with quantity of employees (for which city doesn't much %i%) and empty value in City is shown.

Comment: @khris To stop this chase I'd still very much like you to show me a table with expected results from data you posted in question.

Comment: @khris Why are we talking about employees who do not have a department? I don't see them in results, so the first query should answer that question.

Answer (score 3):

Do this:

```
select depart.CITY, count (*) as numb 
from depart inner join empl on empl.DEBT=depart.DEBT
where depart.CITY like '%i%'
group by depart.CITY;
```

WHERE comes first before GROUP BY

Comment: @lamwaiman1988 one hour ago, it's reversed. GROUP BY, then WHERE. see the OP's edit

Answer (score 3):

`WHERE` clause comes before `GROUP BY` clause.
Like this:

```
SELECT depart.CITY, COUNT (*) AS numb 
FROM depart INNER JOIN empl ON empl.DEBT=depart.DEBT
WHERE depart.CITY LIKE '%i%'    
GROUP BY depart.CITY;
```

[See this fiddle for WHERE clause.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/59ee4/2)

Or you can also use `HAVING` clause
Like this:

```
SELECT depart.CITY, COUNT (*) AS numb 
FROM depart INNER JOIN empl ON empl.DEBT=depart.DEBT
GROUP BY depart.CITY
HAVING depart.CITY LIKE '%i%';
```

[See this fiddle for HAVING clause.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/59ee4/1)

It is more likely to use `HAVING` clause.
[See this link for more details](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/group_by.php)